# rake db:create "unknown could'n parse YAML" sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parsing, sqlite, rake, yaml

Hi I am trying to add a db to my rails app. I have created a db using sqlite3 called proto_development but when I go to use the rake db:create command I get the following error

```
    ROOT\first_app>rake db:create --trace
    ** Invoke db:create (first_time)
    ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
    ** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
    ** Execute rails_env
    ** Execute db:load_config
    rake aborted!
    (<unknown>): couldn't parse YAML at line 9 column 12
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse_stream'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:125:in `parse'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:112:in `load'
    ROOT/first_app/sqlite3-ruby/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:
    100:in `database_configuration'
    ROOT/first_app/sqlite3-ruby/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/database
    s.rake:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
    C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<main>'
    Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config
```

Below is my YAML file:
        # SQLite version 3.x
        #   gem install sqlite3
        #   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
        #   gem 'sqlite3'

```
    development:

      adapter: sqlite3

      database: db/proto_development.sqlite3

      pool: 5

      timeout: 5000
      username: root
      password: "p"




    # Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and

    # re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".

    # Do not set this db to the same as development or production.

    test:

      adapter: sqlite3

      database: db/test.sqlite3

      pool: 5

      timeout: 5000
      username: root
      password: "p" 




    production:

      adapter: sqlite3

      database: db/production.sqlite3

      pool: 5
      timeout: 5000
      username: root
      password: "p"
```

---

Any help you could offer would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you try using http://pastie.org instead? It's hard to tell the line that's giving an error.

Comment: I have put it on pastie please follow this link http://pastie.org/pastes/3082439

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your password in your database.yml file is a string, as in not all numbers. For example, 321 would pull an error, b321 would work. This may work.